# Force ffmpeg to output WAV_FORMAT_PCM

Tags: ffmpeg, wav

It seems that the format code of any wav file output by ffmpeg (using version 2.8.1) that contains a sampling rate higher than 48000 (such as 88200 or 96000) will have the WAV_FORMAT_EXTENSIBLE format instead of WAV_FORMAT_PCM. Even if it is a 2 channel source with 16-bit depth, or if these settings are forced with `-ac 2 -acodec pcm_s16le`.

Why does ffmpeg do this? Is there any command line option to force WAV_FORMAT_PCM to be written as the format, no matter the sampling rate? Resampling is too slow. If no command line option is available, where can I begin looking in the source code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't find any reference why, maybe it's not common. The [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/dn653308(v=vs.85).aspx) page only mentions multiple channels and high-resolution.

The relevant code is in [libavformat/riffenc.c](https://github.com/FFmpeg/FFmpeg/blob/235381e674bf0921cbb7871946e2ff08bd84d6ba/libavformat/riffenc.c#L72):

```
  waveformatextensible = (enc->channels > 2 && enc->channel_layout) ||
                           enc->sample_rate > 48000 ||
                           enc->codec_id == AV_CODEC_ID_EAC3 ||
                           av_get_bits_per_sample(enc->codec_id) > 16;
```